# Differential of a map on $M(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Could someone please verify that I got this problem correct or not:

Let $f: M(n,\mathbb{R}) \to M(n,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(A)=A^T+A.$ Calculate $Df_A$

Mt attempt:

Consider differential map $f_{*,A}: T_A M(n,\mathbb{R}) \to T_{f(A)} M(n,\mathbb{R})$. Note that $T_{A}M(n,\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R^{n^2}}$. Now (using a result) for any matrix $X\in \mathbb{\mathbb{R^{n^2}}}$, there is curve $c(t)$ in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ with $c(0)=A$ and $c'(0)=X$, note the following:

$f_{*,A}(X)= \frac{d}{dt}f(c(t))|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}(c(t)^T + c(t))|_{t=0}=(c'(t)^T + c'(t) )|_{t=0}=c'(0)^T+c'(0)=X^T+X$.

Hence $Df_A=X^T+X$. Does it make sense? or did I miss something.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Your "hence" statement doesn't quite make sense. What you mean to write is $Df_A(X) = X + X^\top$ (I don't know why you confusingly switched the order of the terms).

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks for pointing out I have changed the function as $f(A)=A^T + A$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: @Rashmi The above comment refers to the last equality $Df_A = X^T + X$: there is no $X$ on the LHS and no $A$ on the RHS

Comment: @Rashmi By the way, your proof seems OK but you could just have checked the definition: write $f(A+H)  = f(A) + Df_A(H) + o(\|H\|)$.